# Relationship between $(2^n)^{th}$ prime and its bits

Tags: prime-numbers

How many bits does it take to write the $p_{2^n}$, the $(2^n)^{th}$ prime number in binary where the first one is 2, second 3, third 5 et cetera.

Is it about $n$? E.g., if I take the product $p_{2^{25}}p_{2^{50}} = x$ then will $x$ be approximately $25+50=75$ bits?

Comment: Hint : Use Pierre Dusart's bounds for the $n$ th prime number.

Comment: This is not a homework problem, I could set-up my experiment better if I can tell this efficiently. Could I get more than a hint?

Comment: $n\cdot 2^n\cdot \log 2$ has how many bits?

Comment: Assuming $\log = \log_2$, we have about $\log_2(n) + n + 1$ bits?